# LaTeX Math operations

Tags: math-mode, calc

I am trying to add two values and then multiply them by a number but in order to do it in that order I have to use parentheses. The problem is that when I add parentheses I get a compilation error.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
 \value{#2} is 10. 
 \value{#1} is 5.

(\value{#1}+\value{#2})*.5
```

The value I am trying to attain is 7.5. The above code gives me errors only when adding the parentheses.

If I do the the equation without the parentheses I would get 10.

Important note, I have no way of knowing the 2 values in `#1` or `#2`, I only put values for an example.

For more context this is being done in a node.

```
\path (\value{#1}+\value{#2}*.5,-\value{cou}),-\value{cou}) node(msg) {node msg}
```

my solution right now is i make a counter and add the two values then multiply by 1/2.

Current solution

```
\newcounter{avg}
\addtocounter{avg}{\value{#1}+\value{#2}}
\path (\value{avg}*.5,-\value{cou}) node(msg) {node msg}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please provide more of the context, e.g. a small copmilable document containing the snippet and generating the error.  Are you trying to define a macro? Are you working with lengths? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of the context will be better. Maybe this isn't a finally answer.

I think the [`xfp`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfp.pdf), with `fpeval`, can do this for you. A simple example using section number to add and multiply.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\def\a{\fpeval{\value{section}*2+1}}

\def\b{\fpeval{round(sqrt(2)+2,3)}}

\newcommand\ccc[2]{%
    \fpeval{(#1 * #2)*.5}}

\begin{document}

\section{test 1}
\a
\section{test 2}
\a

\begin{center}
\b

\ccc{2}{5}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: \fpeval{(\value{#1}+\value{#2})/2} this is what i did to make it work thanks